# Large number of sessions created per user when using Laravel as an API

Tags: angularjs, session, laravel-4, redis

I'm using laravel as an API, and frontend purely based on html5 and angular. There are many separate api calls on some pages.

I've noticed that, with each request to the API from my frontend, a new session is created on laravel.

I don't know if these sessions are a problem? I've set a small expiration time (just two minutes), but when there is a lot of traffic, is there is a chance of overwhelming redis? As in, a chance of overwhelming redis before other parts of the server get similarly stretched necessitating an upgrade? Is there a workaround?

Should I try to make angular hold on to just one session in the backend? Can't say I really relish *that* concept. I mean to say, I already use something like that for the auth token session, but also maintaining a session for 'everything in general' as well seems vile.

(the 'auth token' session is generated and stored manually and has a separate expiration time, so this does not cause problems with the small expiration times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are authenticating with a token for each request there is no need for Laravel to store sessions. You can disable sessions by removing the driver in `app/config/session.php` (setting it to nothing).

Comment: That sounds awesome! I hope no other parts of the system (mis)use sessions for anything else...

Comment: Oops, that didn't quite work, the Manager class was complaining about a missing constructor argument. Setting it to `array` worked.